# How to read a specific line in a data file in FORTRAN 77

Tags: file, fortran

I have an external data file which contains several lines with values of parameters. This file is used as input data file for several FORTRAN codes. However, each code does not need all the data. Currently, all codes read the entire data file and keep each one whatever is needed. But, I want to improve this. Each code reads the external data file using the following commands

```
OPEN(UNIT=10,FILE='input.par',STATUS='UNKNOWN')
READ(10,*)val1
READ(10,*)val2
READ(10,*)val3
..............
READ(10,*)valn
CLOSE(10)
```

So, how can I `OPEN` the data file and read, let's say for example, only line 4 or lines 1 and 7?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, to read just the first and seventh numbers:

```
read (10, *) val1

do i=1, 5
   read (10, *)
end do

read (10, *) val7
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and apt response!